# Office365 Api token validation

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Hi Guys I am getting the issue "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217" While calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me with Bearer Token.
please help me to fix this one issue.

Comment: How are you getting the access token? Can you confirm it's a valid JWT by decoding it? I'm not endorsing tools, but there's plenty of free JWT decoders out there

Comment: If you are making a post call to login.microsoftonline.com, please post the body of the request without secrets so we can help debug